# Symmetric difference or addition on power set?

Tags: ring-theory

In my text book, it shows that

$3\{1,2\}=\{1,2\}+\{1,2\}+\{1,2\}$

$=(\{1,2\}+\{1,2\})+\{1,2\}$

$= \emptyset +\{1,2\}$

$=\{1,2\}$

Here, I don't understand how $(\{1,2\}+\{1,2\})$ became $\emptyset$. Help!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that $+$ here denotes the symmetric difference: if $A$ and $B$ are sets,

$$A+B=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)\;.$$

Thus, for any set $A$ we have

$$A+A=(A\setminus A)\cup(A\setminus A)=\varnothing\cup\varnothing=\varnothing\;,$$

and

$$\varnothing+A=(\varnothing\setminus A)\cup(A\setminus\varnothing)=\varnothing\cup A=A\;.$$

Thus, $3A=(A+A)+A=\varnothing+A=A$ for any set $A$ at all, not just for $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: Thanks, but what \ means ?

Comment: @Wes: Set difference: $A\setminus B=\{x:x\in A\text{ and }x\notin B\}$, the set of things that are in $A$ but not in $B$. $A+B$ then works out to be the set of things that are in **exactly one** of $A$ and $B$.